# How to set up minimal vertical height for website?

Tags: html, css

Here is my site - http://www.aspenwebsites.com/majesticpines/about/

I noticed if I reduce the height of my viewport the bottom area of my sidebar (the one with email subscription field) overlaps my site's navigation.

I was wondering if there is a way to set up some minimum height for the site, so that if it reaches that value it shows scroll-bar on the right and doesn't reduce further, thus my email subscription form doesn't overlap with navigation links.

I tried to set up `min-height:700px` and `overflow-y:auto` for the `BODY` tag and also for `.header-sidebar`, but that didn't make any difference.

Could you advise what am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use css media queries.

```
// The CSS queries inside this @media will applied when the viewport height is lesser than 1001px
@media screen and (max-height: 1000px) {
    // Reduce menu paddings and margins here
    // Example:
    .menu li {
        padding:2px 0;
        margin-top:3px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it wasn't able to do what I wanted, but may be it is not possible due to some elements being absolutely positioned. But I used your advise and adjusted some elements using media queries. Although it hasn't fully solved the issue, it made things much better :) Thank you.

Comment: As I see the website resize now looks ok!

If it helped you vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is the one you have mentioned that it is not working - set correct min-height to some element. But you have to target the element which contains both navigation and the email subscription. If you set it to that element than it should work unless you are using some kind of wierd stuff which would overwrite its min-height (I can imagine javascript which would do this kind of stuff easily).

If you want more help then please share the corresponding code in fiddle where we can work the error out.

Comment: Thank you for taking a moment to look into my question. I'm not using JS, but I do have absolute positioning on the parent div that contains email signup, so that it always stays at the bottom. I am not very familiar with feedle, but I'll try to put my code in there and will let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add "overflow-y: auto;" to your style for your `<div id="navbar" class="navbar">` line (not to box-scroll which encases it), then a scrollbar will appear if the window isn't high enough to display your navbar.  However the footer part of that area still overwrites the lower part of the scroll area.  Is there a reason you separate the sign-up & copyright part from the nav?  If you make it a part of the nav then it should just be part of the scroll area without overlap.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I like to keep the subscription at the bottom, I think it makes the sidebar look cleaner and more balanced on white space distribution.